# Can we edit the picture in Android to set the Radius of the pics on the edges?

Tags: android, graphics, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to know if we can edit the picture that we take from a camera and store it on our Phone. Can we make use of android.graphics package to edit the picture.

One of the sample picture has has been edited on the top width is this as you can see the image has been clipped from the top center just below the word "Discovery". Is this possible on Andriod?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) out of a bitmap, and then use canvas drawing commands to mutate and save it again.

I'm not really sure what you're asking, though.